# Summer internship visa for Germany

Tags: visa, germany

I am an Indian passport holder studying in the U.K. on a tier 4 visa. 
I have been offered a 3 month summer internship in Germany (from July to September). I have decided with the employer whether it will be paid or unpaid.

What sort of visa will I require (for paid and unpaid)? Will I need a work/residence permit?

Answer (score 1):

As a non EU citizen then you will require a visa to perform an Internship in Germany.  If it is paid or not does not make a difference to the visa.

These website provide some additional information:

- [Germany Training/Internship Visa](https://www.germany-visa.org/training-internship-visa/),
- [Student Internship Visa](https://visaguide.world/europe/germany-visa/long-stay/student-internship/).

Your employer should help you through the process.